# Unable to execute awk command in PHP script

Tags: php, awk

```
<?php
$dd="lastDateTemplate-28-11-2013.csv";
$c_row=exec("awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," } ; { print $1 }'" .$dd);
?>
```

I am not able to execute AWK command in PHP.

Below is the error -:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '='

Answer (score 2):

```
$c_row=exec("awk 'BEGIN { FS = \",\" } ; { print $1 }'" .$dd,$output);
```

all the output lines printed will be captured in $output ,that is passed as the argument.

you can access output from the `$output`

[exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Comment: Hi Bhadra thank u for your help . But I am not getting any out put for this how should I print the result returned by AWK . Script just hangs out without giving any put. Please help